# Novel about a high school student werewolf meeting a girl (Elise) who becomes a vampire

Tags: story-identification, horror, childrens-novel, vampire, werewolf

I'm searching for an old novel I read back in high school. It involved the main protagonist being a high school student who is also a Lycan (werewolf). It's set in high school, where she meets a new girl, named Elise. Somewhere down the lines, Elise becomes seduced by a stranger, and turned into a vampire.

That stranger is also targeting other students, and it's up to the protagonist, and a friend knowledgeable about the supernatural to put a stop to him. Prior to Elise being turned, there was no active conflict between the vampires and werewolves.

Eventually, the protagonist manages to track him down, with Elise helping her, at the expense of her life.

The only other info I can muster up is that the book is from the late 80's - early 90's from the cover art, although I read it in my high school in 2008.

Comment: Do they actually use the term "Lycan"?

Comment: http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/7785207-the-mating - I think this might be porn, btw. But the main character is called Elise and there are werewolves and vampires.

Comment: This also fits albeit it's rather newer. Not 1980s; http://figment.com/books/348056-Immortal-Siblings-Vol-1-The-Bond

Comment: Yes, the term Lycan is used.

Comment: https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/30123368-my-blood-approves also mentions Vampires and Lycans, and has both an Alice and later an Elise, but it's also too recent with 2010.

Comment: @FuzzyBoots  my first thought was, I don't remember seeing the word lycan before the turn of the century, certainly not in the '80s.

Comment: @Seeds: First I remember of it was Underworld in 2003, although Google NGrams disagrees with me. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Lycan%2CLycanthrope%2CWerewolf&year_start=1940&year_end=2016&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CLycan%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CLycanthrope%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CWerewolf%3B%2Cc0

Comment: Honestly, I don't know if I've every seen it written, except relating to the Underworld movies. But I certainly have seen lycanthrope used a bunch of times, in many places, makes me think that ngram got something reversed. One source actually indicates that Lycan isn't even correct usage, as it simply means wolf. (not werewolf)

Comment: Were the lycans and vampires at war, or just coexisting? Examples of vampire vs. werewolf wars are very sparse before 1991.

Comment: From what I can gather.

Author must not be well known/

Comment: As per the last time you posted this, were the vampires and werewolves in active conflict or did it start with Elise being turned?

Comment: It started after Elise got turned. More and more students were disappearing.

The Protagonist is friends with another student whom was pretty knowledgeable with the supernatural, too, if that helps.

Comment: And do you still think this was a series?

Comment: I know for a fact there were a few books in the series. But this particular installment was the only one involving vampires.

Comment: If it helps at all, the novel was written in a 1st person point of view, also.

Answer (score 5):

[*Hunters' Moon*](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0425143627) by Debra Doyle and James D. Macdonald

> Valerie Sherwood, teenage werewolf, tries to protect her town from a
>   group of vampires and the hunters who have come to destroy them, in
>   the sequel to the authors' Bad Blood.

The preview on Amazon starts with excerpt where Val finds Elise's parents dead:

> I'd come here to find out how my friend Elise could be a vampire
>   without her parents knowing. It looked like I'd just found out.

Answer (score 2):

You might mean *The Law of the Lycans* book series by Nicky Charles. The entire series has 8 books in total, so I do not know what book you might be taking about if it does belong to this series, so I will reveal the first two pages of the first book, **The Mating**.

> She lay beside him, staring blankly at the ceiling. The deed was done. They were mated. It didn’t matter that she had no love for him nor he for her. Political alliances were more important than feelings, or so she had been told. That fact was cold comfort right now as her heart broke within her.
>
> Beside her, he stirred and she sensed him rolling over, his amber eyes staring at her. She made no move to look at him and instead tried to steady her breathing. It was no use. As she inhaled, her breath quivered betraying her emotional state. Despite blinking rapidly, a stray tear trailed
>   down her cheek.
>
> The covers rustled beside her and then she felt his finger move across her cheek, catching the tear. “I’m sorry, Elise.” Kane’s voice was deep yet gentle.
>
> “It doesn’t matter.” She answered quietly, still staring at the ceiling. What he was apologising for, she was unsure. For mating her? For the inevitable pain the first time brought? For the fact
>   that she was now bound to him for the rest of her life, despite her love for another? Perhaps he was sorry for all three, yet they were as beyond his control as they were hers. She swallowed
>   hard. “It couldn’t be helped.”
>
> “No, it couldn’t,” he agreed, sighing heavily. His arm slipped around her waist and drew her closer. She let her cheek rest against his muscular chest, too spent to protest; the sound of his steady heartbeat faintly comforting. “I wish I could have given you more time to get to know me
>   before we mated, but the Elders are awaiting proof of our union.”
>
> She felt heat flood her cheeks at the thought of the blood stained sheets being examined as proof of her virginity. It was so old fashioned but it was how things were done to ensure the blood lines between the packs were truly mixed. Heaven forbid she’d come into the relationship tainted with another male’s pup in her belly. Well, there could be no doubt now that Kane was her first and only mate.
>
> ---
>
> Tradition or not, it still didn’t lessen her embarrassment. All her friends and family would see and know the intimacy that had occurred between her and Kane. Worst of all, Bryan—the one she loved—would know as well.
>
> Closing her eyes, scenes from the past day flashed through her mind. She’d just returned from a run with Bryan where they’d frolicked and played in the cool shaded woods that surrounded her home. He’d been her best friend since they were pups and recently the friendship had grown into
>   something more. Bryan had hinted that he would ask her father for permission to become her mate and she’d been thrilled at the idea. Many of her friends were already mated and, as her nineteenth birthday approached, she was becoming restless, eager to experience bonding with
>   another.
>
> Already, she’d gone through two heat cycles but her father had held off choosing her a mate. Elise had naively thought he was waiting for her to find someone who suited her. Ruefully, she now acknowledged that was never the case. While her father loved her, he was first and foremost their Alpha and had to put the well-being of the pack ahead of all else. Her older
>   brother and sister had mated with packs to the north and south. With the sea at their back, it was only to the east that an alliance was needed. When Kane became the new Alpha of that territory, the Elders determined that a mating between the packs was needed to ensure continued stability.
>
> That day, as she returned laughing at something Bryan had said, Jake, her father’s Beta, had greeted her at the door. “Elise, you are needed in the assembly room.”
>
> Something in his tone of voice warned her that all was not well. With a slight wave to her friend, she followed Jake, wondering what could possible require her presence. The assembly room was used on occasion for general pack meetings but usually her father and the council of Elders dealt
>   with all important issues.
>
> As she pushed the door open, a cacophony of emotions hit her. Excitement, worry, curiosity... She was sensitive to moods and puzzled over the strange mixture. Her eyes scanned the room. The Elders seemed excited and pleased and were conversing with another group of older persons who were strangers to her. Her father was frowning and talking to a man of about twenty-five.
>   Elise hadn’t encountered him before and took a moment to study this new arrival.
>
> The man was taller than her father, at least six foot four, and powerfully built. His shoulders were broad and muscles could be seen rippling beneath his shirt as he moved, gesturing to make some point. Dark, faintly messy hair topped a pleasing face, with sculpted cheeks and a full bottom lip. Possibly sensing her inspection of him, he glanced toward the door and his amber eyes locked on hers. There was a hard edge about him. Slowly he studied her from head to foot, lingering on her breasts and then her hips, before returning to her face. Elise felt herself flush under his scrutiny. As he flashed a brief smile at her, she thought she caught a glimpse of
>   softness in his eyes but it was quickly gone. He looked back at her father and continued speaking with him as if dismissing her presence.
>
> Her father glanced her way, sighed and ended the conversation. He walked towards her with a scowl on his face. “Elise, you’ve been running again, I see.”