# 80s-90s book about a high school student werewolf who meets a girl who becomes a vampire

Tags: story-identification, vampire, werewolf

The name currently escapes me, but the story goes along the lines of that the protagonist, a high school student, who is a werewolf, meets a new student by the name of Elise.

Somewhere down the lines, she meets a stranger, and ends up becoming a vampire. That stranger is also targeting other students, and it's up to the protagonist, and a friend knowledgeable about the supernatural to put a stop to him. Prior to Elise being turned, there was not active conflict between the vampires and werewolves.

The only other info I can muster up is the book is from the late 80's - early 90's from the cover art, although I read it in my high school in 2008.

Comment: Welcome back. I see you have more details this time?

Comment: Please don't post [the same question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/146678/fantasy-novel-with-main-protagonist-called-elise-lycans-and-vampires-feature-pr) more than once. Instead you should [edit](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/posts/146678/edit) your previous question as you recall more details - editing it bumps it onto the front page almost as if it's a new post.

Comment: There, I undeleted the other question and merged the two. That way, the one that stays (as well as being the original post) is also the one with upvotes, so you get to keep the reputation you gained :-)